# Titanium button.backgroundGradient focus

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I am working on a Titanium  mobile app and I have a problem with buttonfocusing while using backgroundRadient .

I meet success using the touchstart event (changeBackgroundGradient is simple enough to avoid display here):

```
authButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    changeBackgroundGradient(authButton);
});
```

But the touchend event is not what I want. It fires only if the user end the touch **on the element** (behaves as a click event).
Touchmove is not what I want either, as it fires as soon as the user moves.

```
authButton.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    revertBackgroundGradient(authButton);
});
```

What I want is: as long as the user is touching the button, the button is on focus. Something like 'ontap' and 'onrelease'.
I know there are backgroundFocusedColor and backgroundFocusedImage, but no backgroundFocusedGradient.

**How can I handle button focus while using backgroundGradient property?**
I want to have the default behaviour but it seems to stop as soon as I use the backgroundGradient property.

Thanks.

--edit:

Here is the full code :

```
        // Authenticate Button
    var authButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width : '50%',
        height : '60',
        top : '15',
        bottom : '15',
        title : L('LoginView_authButton'),
        font: {
            fontSize: 20,
            fontFamily: 'TrebuchetMS-Bold'
        },
        color : '#FFFFFF',
        textAlign : 'center',
        borderColor : '#3D86A9',
        borderWidth : '2',
        borderRadius : '5',
        backgroundGradient : {
            type : 'linear',
            startPoint : {
                x : '0%',
                y : '0%'
            },
            endPoint : {
                x : '0%',
                y : '100%'
            },
            colors : [{
                color : '#a2d6eb',
                offset : 0.0
            }, {
                color : '#67afcf',
                offset : 0.5
            }, {
                color : '#3591bc',
                offset : 0.5
            }, {
                color : '#1e83b1',
                offset : 1.0
            },
            ]
        }
    });

    authButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        changeBackgroundGradient(authButton);
    });

    authButton.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        revertBackgroundGradient(authButton);
    });

    function changeBackgroundGradient(AuthButton)
{
    AuthButton.backgroundGradient = {
        type : 'linear',
        startPoint : {
            x : '0%',
            y : '0%'
        },
        endPoint : {
            x : '0%',
            y : '100%'
        },
        colors : [{
            color : '#f5bd8b',
            offset : 0.0
        }, {
            color : '#e59a57',
            offset : 0.5
        }, {
            color : '#da7a23',
            offset : 0.5
        }, {
            color : '#c35211',
            offset : 1.0
        },
        ]
    };
}

function revertBackgroundGradient(AuthButton)
{
    AuthButton.backgroundGradient = {
        type : 'linear',
        startPoint : {
            x : '0%',
            y : '0%'
        },
        endPoint : {
            x : '0%',
            y : '100%'
        },
        colors : [{
            color : '#9FD3E9',
            offset : 0.0
        }, {
            color : '#63AAC9',
            offset : 0.5
        }, {
            color : '#348BB8',
            offset : 0.5
        }, {
            color : '#2081B2',
            offset : 1.0
        },
        ]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the trick using touchCancel

```
authButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    changeBackgroundGradient(authButton);
});

authButton.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(e) {
    revertBackgroundGradient(authButton);
});
```

I first misunderstood the documentation:

**touchcancel**
*Fired when a touch event is interrupted by the device*

The touch event is indeed interrupted by the device if you end the touch **outside** the element. So it works as intended : as long as you press the screen, the button is orange, once you release the press outside of the button, the button goes back blue.

Thanks for your hints Sismetic, it made me figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Oh ok, I get it now, it works as intended, it's not a bug, as you're adding the event listener TO the button, so it only applies to the button.

You might want to add a property to authButton called isFocused or something like that. And on the touchstart event, add:

```
authButton.isFocused:true;
```

And then add the touchend event on the view/window that contains the authButton with the revert function.

Do you see why?

Comment: Exactly. The default behaviour actually but it seems to stop as soon as I put a backgroundGradient.

Comment: Ok... could you add an alert after calling the function? Btw, did you wrote changeBackgroundGradient()?

Comment: Yes I wrote everything.

Maybe there is a misunderstanding : I am able to see both the change (original blue to orange) and the revert (orange to original blue), but I want the change to stay as long as the user keeps his finger on the button. Very much like the default behaviour of buttons and like the :hover css class.

Comment: So what it does is, make the change, then revert without you ending the touch?

Comment: It reverts only if I end the touch ON the button (wich is a click and activate the click event).
It doesn't revert if I end the touch anywhere else. I want to it end when I end the touch no matter where I end it.

Comment: Sadly there is no such thing as isFocused. I can't find any mention of 'focus' property anywhere.